# Not shown page after login into my account

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver           
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import requests
from csv import writer


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20) 

time.sleep(2)
url='https://app.vidiq.com/auth/login'

driver.get(url)

email=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#email")
email.send_keys("-----")

password=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#password")
password.send_keys("--------")

time.sleep(2)
login=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@type='submit']")
login.click()
```

they will successfully  login to the page but after  they will not show me the `dashboard` page and then the program will end kindly can you tell me what issue will be there  not shown me page

Not show these `Dashboard page`: [image]

Comment: You got a pair of Demo creds for us to test?